# Using SimpleCov to display Cucumber code coverage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, simplecov

Does anyone have any experience using Cucumber and the code coverage tool SimpleCov?  I'd added the following lines env.rb file so Cucumber will fire off SimpleCov-

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
SimpleCov.coverage_dir 'coverage/cucumber'
```

It does what it is supposed EXCEPT that the output file lists 0 files test, 0 relevent lines, 0 lines covered, etc.  Any idea how I can make the code coverage come out right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SimpleCov statement has to be the very first thing in the `env.rb` file, before the other requires.  Then it appears to work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Got this when using RSpec too, even when I made sure that I had:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
```

at the very top of my `spec/spec_helper.rb` file.  Turns out that I had accidentally required my code library under test after `require 'spec_helper'` in the actual spec file (i.e.: `foo_spec.rb`) (D'oh! ... Needed more sleep that day...)

So tip for newbies or sleep-deprived code junkies alike: Make sure you're actually requiring SimpleCov and starting the coverage analysis at the very beginning of your actual load order.